# System.NotSupportedException was unhandled by user code, LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2012, model-view-controller

I am new in MVC asp.net i am developing a project where i want to add floors sequence wise. Want to start sequence from 0.

Message=LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'NTB.Floor LastOrDefault[Floor](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[NTB.Floor], System.Linq.Expressions.Expression`1[System.Func`2[NTB.Floor,System.Boolean]])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
    {

        var cfloorno = 0;

        //if (bid > 0)
        //{
            var lastfloor = db.Floors.Last(x => x.BuildingId == id);

            if (lastfloor != null)
            {
                cfloorno = lastfloor.FloorNo.GetValueOrDefault() + 1;
            }

        //}
        var building = db.Buildings.ToList();
        ViewBag.Building = building;
        var type = db.FloorTypes.ToList();
        ViewBag.Type = type;
        ViewBag.CurrentFloor = cfloorno;
        ViewBag.buildingid = id;
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Create(Floor f)
    {
        using (db)
        {
            db.Floors.Add(f);
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("List");
    }
```

**View:**

```
<input type="hidden" name="BuildingId" value="@ViewBag.buildingid" />
<div class="row">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Floor #</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
        <input class="form-control" name="FloorNo" value="@ViewBag.CurrentFloor" disabled type="number">
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FloorNo)
    </div>
</div>
```